# How do I "schedule an interrupt" on win32/intel architecture?

Tags: winapi, interrupt

I'd like to figure out how to schedule a real [ISR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms892408.aspx) on normal win32 architecture (not Windows CE!)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by schedule? You can hook a Hardware interrupt (and you should save and call the old hook in most cases); you can trigger a HW interrupt manually - but there consequences when handling those; you can hook one of the timer int's, and implement a scheduling mechanism, but AFAIK you can't "schedule an ISR".